# How to put <table> inside <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

Is it good solution to put `table` inside `a` tag ? Why link doesn't work when it wraps table ?

```
<a href="/place">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="place-icon" />
      </td>
      <td> 
        My place name
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

Comment: Your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/4UrtT/

Comment: Can you please rephrase you're opening line and title, such that it would be more helpful for someone searching for something similar? I don't think anybody is going to look for *implement the next html*..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to implement the next html

No, you don't, and shouldn't. Really. It's invalid, non-semantic, and (perhaps most importantly) won't work reliably because of those reasons.

If all you want is an image and some text (which is linked), use something like:

```
<a href="/place" class="button">My Place Name</a>

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url();
    background-position: 2px 2px;
    padding-left: 16px; /* size of image */
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RvTp3/

Per comments, here is another example showing an image aligned to the vertical middle when the text wraps: http://jsfiddle.net/RvTp3/1/

Comment: Nice comment, but I need to align image "vertically middle" http://jsfiddle.net/rPsEJ/

Comment: BTW there is another problem, if you want to decrease 'line-height: 32px;' the image will be cropped

Comment: You can experiment with `min-height` instead of 'line-height` (or using a reduced `line-height`. If you get stuck, you can open another question.

Comment: after min-height the text is not centered (

Comment: Here are some more complex layouts you can play with. If you don't know the size of the image or the text it is more complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/RvTp3/4/

Comment: One reason why I want to do it is because layout in Emails is problematic without tables.

Comment: @Gherman I agree that email often requires using tables for overall layout. This still results in valid HTML; it's just a deviation from normal good practice. Putting a table inside an anchor is invalid, so you might end up with unpredictable results if the email client/server tries to inspect/clean the markup before rendering. I'd try other approaches before putting a table into an anchor, but if it's the only thing that works, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me, that you just want to have a link with icon and text, both linking to /place and that you use `<table>` just for the layout, right? Why not get rid off the table and do the layout using css?

Comment: yes, but how to align text and image vertically like on http://jsfiddle.net/rPsEJ/

Comment: @OlegDats, as shown in the example of Tim Medora above, you can tweak the alignment of the image by setting the `background-position` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. You shouldn't.

if you want to enable **click** on table. then you can just do it by attaching click event to table.

```
 <table  onclick="window.location='yoururl'">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="place-icon" />
      </td>
      <td> 
        My place name
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: The question is: should you do that?